Building python3-scipy for Kirkstone
I am trying to install the python3-scipy for Yocto/Kirkstone.
Using the inbuilt command pipoe , I installed the package.
pipoe --python python3 --package scipy --licenses MIT
This command worked & the respective recipes were installed.
Compiled & Built the image.
bitbake kirkstone-image.bb
In the work directory, I see it as
Observed Output:
cd /build/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-linux-gnueabi/python3-scipy/1.13.0-r0/
tree image
└── usr
    └── lib
        └── python3.10
            └── site-packages
                └── UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info
                    ├── LICENSES_bundled.txt
                    ├── LICENSE.txt
                    ├── METADATA
                    ├── RECORD
                    ├── top_level.txt
                    └── WHEEL

It is building as UNKNOWN.
From this URL : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/dev/toolchain.html
I can see it is supported w.r.t my Python version.
python3-scipy recipe file
SUMMARY = "Fundamental algorithms for scientific computing in Python"
HOMEPAGE = "https://scipy.org/"
AUTHOR = "None <None>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=5f477c3073ea2d02a70a764319f5f873"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/a3/328965862f41ba67d27ddd26205962007ec87d99eec6d364a29bf00ac093/scipy-1.13.0.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "6c6c404e2cf783374587c9f012d622bc"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "58569af537ea29d3f78e5abd18398459f195546bb3be23d16677fb26616cc11e"

S = "${WORKDIR}/scipy-1.13.0"

DEPENDS += "python3-numpy-native python3-cython-native lapack openblas libgfortran gcc-runtime python3-pybind11-native python3-wheel-native python3-pythran-native"

RDEPENDS:${PN} += "openblas lapack libgfortran python3-numpy python3-pybind11 cmake"

CLEANBROKEN = "1"
DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS = "--fcompiler=gfortran"

#inherit setuptools3-base
#inherit setuptools3_legacy
#inherit setuptools3
inherit python_setuptools_build_meta
inherit pkgconfig

Misc Details:
Target Architecture - ARM
Yocto Version - Kirkstone
Host Server - Ubuntu 22.04LTS
Python Version - 3.10.7

As a workaround what I did was, I cloned the meta-scipy layer.
git clone -b branch_name https://github.com/tuxable-ltd/meta-scipy meta-scipy


I used the dunfell branch.
I made the respective changes to the recipe as required and built the image. Works as expected.

Python3-scipy version 1.8.1.
Although this a workaround solution, the original issue has not been identified correctly.
Note:
The above layer is no longer maintained and it has been archived.
